# LogStash returns 200 OK even on malformed requests

Tags: logstash, http-error

I am testing LogStash using Postman, and I tried posting a request to `localhost:5556/debug/warning` with a malformed or missing body (for example JSON that has `{{{` and no closing brackets) to see what error I'll get. To my surprise, LogStash still gives me 200 OK. I assumed I would get a 400 Bad Request or similar.

It even returns 200 OK if the ES instance to which it connects is missing (and the /health check reports failure to connect in that case).

Is that normal for LogStash?

Comment: Can you show the configuration your have? And which Logstash version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the http input plugin to receive your request, the json codec is used only if the `Content-Type` is `application/json` (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html#_description_16)). So that can explain why, in the case of malformed json, the 200 code is returned.

For the case of the missing ES instance, the 200 code just signal that the request has been received by the http input plugin and that the request has been transmitted to the queue to be treated by the next plugins in the pipeline (you can take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-http/blob/7fb9f850218190baecbdfb7f63c5f6dc71d47598/lib/logstash/inputs/http.rb#L140)).

When the elasticsearch output plugin fails to send the request to elasticsearch, the http input plugin has already send the 200 code saying that it has correctly received the message.

Comment: I was application/json, though.

Comment: Then I have no idea why you got 200 as response to a malformed json.